# Bash and Ksh background color - PS1

Tags: bash, shell, ksh, colors

To change the back color my command is :

```
PS1='\[\033[46m\]'
```

This works fine for bash but in ksh it will but a [] in front of my server.

Example :

Bash :

```
[USER@SERVER] (in color)
```

Ksh :

```
[][USER@SERVER] (in color)
```

If I wanted it to work in Ksh I would have to write it like this :

```
PS1='\033[46m'
```

Any ideas on making it work for both ksh and bash ?

Comment: See [Using echo -e in PS1 causes line break issues in shell](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/367487)

Comment: Unless I didn't understand the post it's telling me to use ESC characters (which I have done). This allowed me to no longer have overwritting issues in bash but in ksh adds a [] to my prompt

Comment: 'libshedit` is even older than line editing support in ksh and has no problems with character with of the characters in the prompt, since it uses backspace or "print char" to navigate in the command line. The brackets you have with bash are non standard.

Comment: Is that ksh88, ksh93 or one of the pdksh derivatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if [ "$SHELL" == '/bin/bash' ] ; then
  PS1='\[\033[46m\]'
else
  PS1='\033[46m'
fi
```

Comment: What exactly is the $SHELL ?

Comment: SHELL is an environment variable that is set to the current shell (for `ksh` it is set to `/bin/ksh`). Enter `env` in a terminal to see all variables, or `echo $SHELL` to see this specific one.